# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Artifactory for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

After update git plugin, Jenkins pipeline got error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Artifactory for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

My Jenkins pipeline code:

```
stage ('Deploy Artifact') {

             def server = Artifactory.server "Default Artifactory Server"
             def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
             buildInfo.env.capture = true
             buildInfo.env.collect()

             def uploadSpec = """{
```

Artifactory version 2.14.0

Jenkins version : 2.73.2

Please give me an advise ! thank you.

Comment: check your artifactory plugin is valid. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in

Comment: It looks like you don't have the plugin installed.

Comment: thanks, I just re-installed Artifactory, it works fine